# Simple bash code

Tags: bash, shell

I just started learning Bash and I have some problems understanding it. I have the following bash script and I need to know what it does:

```
#!/bin/bash

S=0

for f in $(find . -name "*.c");
do
        S=$(($S + $(wc -l $f | awk ’{ print $1 }’)));

done

echo $S
```

I think it looks for all .c files in the directory and then prints the first column of all lines.

Am I wrong? Can someone explain to me the code?

Comment: Wherever you got this script, you should know that it is terrible! See the page [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). You know what, this alone should be a sign to completely ditch the reference you're reading (and maybe send an email to the author complaining that (s)he's giving wrong information to a learner) and use another better source!

Comment: `find . -name '*.c' -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It counts the amount of lines in all the .c files in the current directory and outputs the total amount of lines in all files.

`find . -name "*.c"` lists all files ending with .c

The for loop goes over all these files, then `wc -l` is used to print the amount of lines in a specific file. Because the default output of wc -l  is `<$bytes> <$filename>`, the `awk '{print $1}` is used to just return the first column of the output, being the amount of bytes, ignoring the filename.

This is stored in the `S` variable, which is appended in the for loop every time. In the end it print the grand total.